# Explicitly calling generic method

Tags: java, generics

If I have an interface and an implementation:

```
interface BaseInterface{ }
class Base implements BaseInterface{ }
```

And somewhere else I have a method:

```
<T extends Base> T foo() { /* return object of class T */ }
```

`foo()` must be explicitly called with Base in order to assign to the interface. **This works just fine**:

```
BaseInterface a = <Base>foo();
```

Fine... but how do I explicitly call the following method?

```
<V extends Base> Map<String, V> bar() { /* return object of Map<String, V> */ }
```

None of these seem to work:

```
Map<String, ? extends BaseInterface> m = <Base>bar();
Map<String, ? extends BaseInterface> m = <String, Base>bar();
Map<String, ? extends BaseInterface> m = <Map<String, Base>>bar();
```

Comment: Use the syntax `SomeClass<T> name = new SomeClass<T>();`

Comment: What about: `Map<String, Base> m = <Map<String, Base>>bar();`?
In your example BaseInterface is not a subtype of Base which causes the error.

Comment: @Kru: exactly, hence you have to explicitly call the method telling it that you want a Map<String, Base> even though you're assigning it to Map<String, BaseInterface>. That is the question.

Comment: @Mark: You *cannot* assign a variable of type `Map<String, Base>` to a variable of type `Map<String, BaseInterface>`. You can't do `Map<String, BaseInterface> m = new HashMap<String, Base>()`, for example, for the same reason that you can't do `List<Object> l = new ArrayList<String>()`. If you could do that it would be possible to insert a `BaseInterface` object that is not a `Base` into the map, violating the generics constraints.

Comment: @CameronSkinner: I don't believe that's true. In the above example `BaseInterface a = <Base>foo();` is valid. You just have to be explicit about the implementation you want from the generic.

Comment: @Mark: `BaseInterface a = <Base>foo()` is fine. But you *cannot* do `Map<String, Base> m1 = new HashMap<String, Base>(); Map<String, BaseInterface> m2 = m1`. Try it and see. The reason is that if you *could* do this, you could then have `m2.put("Something", new BaseInterfaceThatIsNotASubclassOfBase())` which would break the generics contract with `m1`. Thus, that construct is illegal.

Comment: @CameronSkinner: You can do `Map<String, ? extends BaseInterface> m = new HashMap<String, Base>;`. This is how I should have written the question. Either way, I'll give up in defeat on this one because I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that you can do. I still think that not using a generic type in the `bar` signature is the best way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are slightly misunderstanding how to use generics.

What you have now is this:

```
<T extends Base> T foo() {...}
```

which, in English, means that `foo` will return an object that is a subclass of `Base` (remember that subclass means "this class or any child class"). But `foo` doesn't take any arguments so it is impossible for the implementation of `foo` to know what `T` is bound to, nor does it *matter* what `T` is bound to: all `foo` cares about, and all it's callers care about, is that it returns some kind of `Base`.

Essentially, what you have is equivalent to this:

```
Base foo() {...}
```

You don't need to use generics in this case because `foo` doesn't need to worry about type information: it just returns a subclass of `Base`. It would be different if you were doing this:

```
<T extends Base> T doSomething(T input)
```

because `doSomething` needs the generic type information to decide what the return type will be.

Rather than declaring `foo` and `bar` as generics, why not just declare them as

```
Base foo();
Map<String, Base> bar();
```

or, even better,

```
BaseInterface foo();
Map<String, BaseInterface> bar();
```

You can now write your client code:

```
BaseInterface a = foo();
Map<String, BaseInterface> m = bar();
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I think that in your case (given the example code) you don't really need to use generics to solve your problem. It's easy to confuse generics with polymorphism. In this case polymorphism is your friend.

Comment: I have oversimplified the question to shorten its length. I realize this has probably caused confusion. The real question is how do I explicitly call the method `<V extends Base> Map<String, V> bar()`.

Comment: @Mark: The answer still stands: `bar` doesn't take any arguments, so you don't need to use generics. Just declare `bar` to return `Map<String, Base>` and you'll have what you want.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: I have to disagree with your answer. Look at the declaration for the `Collections.emptyList()`, `.emptyMap()`, etc. methods. The declaration is `static <K,V> Map<K,V> emptyMap()`. By your reasoning, why don't they just do `static Map<Object,Object> emptyMap()`? Because then you won't be able to assign it to a `Map<String,Integer>` or something like that. With the way it is declared, you can now do `Map<String,Integer> foo = Collections.<String,Integer>emptyMap()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Base> m = bar<Base>();
```

Accordingly to the code you posted V generic parameter of method bar should be Base or a Base derived class. BaseInterface doesn't derive from Base. It's Base that implement BaseInterface.

Comment: My map is `Map<String, BaseInterface>`... I can't switch it to `Map<String, Base>`.

Comment: then you should eventually change bar signature : <V extends BaseInterface> Map<String, V> bar() { }

Comment: I think you aren't understanding exactly how generics work. Anyway V extends Base and BaseInterface don't extend base. So whatever you are trying to do, it's quite wrong.

Comment: I'm aware of how generics work. Base implements BaseInterface, therefore it is perfectly acceptable to assign a Base to an object of BaseInterface.

Comment: yes but for doing this you don't need generics. please read carefully @Cameron Skinner's answer. He has explained it well.